# Use Array Element as name for another array

Tags: bash

This is probably something that can't be done in `bash`. I have an `if` that searches the elements of an array for a string and then returns the element it finds, which is a web address. What I further need the `if` to do is to check several different arrays by name for the same string and return those matching elements.

So far I have constructed this:

```
  # Array addresses
  node1=( "http://website111.com/detail.php?hostid=12345" "http://website222.com/detail.php?hostid=23456" "http://website333.com/detail.php?hostid=345678" )
  node2_2=( "http://website111.com/detail.php?hostid=456789" "http://website222.com/detail.php?hostid=567890" "http://website333.com/detail.php?hostid=012345" )
  node3_8=( "http://website111.com/detail.php?hostid=112233" "http://website222.com/detail.php?hostid=223344" "http://website333.com/detail.php?hostid=334455" )
  node4_2=( "http://website111.com/detail.php?hostid=556677" "http://website222.com/detail.php?hostid=889900" "http://website333.com/detail.php?hostid=998877" )
  node5_6=( "http://website111.com/detail.php?hostid=887766" "http://website222.com/detail.php?hostid=776655" "http://website333.com/detail.php?hostid=665544" )

  # Array host names
  hosts=( "node1" "node2_2" "node3_8" "node4_2" "node5_6" )

  # String to find
  value="website222"

  # This is as far as I can get
  for ((index=0; index<${#hosts[@]}; index++)); do
#This works for a single named array-->    if [[ "${node2_2[$index]}" =~ (^|[^[:alpha:]])$value([^[:alpha:]]|$) ]]; then
#But here I want to use the array named saved in $hosts-->    if [[ "${hosts[$index]}" =~ (^|[^[:alpha:]])$value([^[:alpha:]]|$) ]]; then
      printf "%s\t%s\n" "$index" "${node2_2[$index]}"
      printf "%s\t%s\n" "$index" "${hosts[$index]}"
    fi
  done
```

I think maybe "eval" can help me here, but I am at a loss for the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without using `eval`. `bash` provides a way to *reference* variable/array names using the name-ref built-ins (`typeset/local or declare -n`) ( needs v4.3 of `bash` at-least).

You can just do

```
for array in "${hosts[@]}"; do
    declare -n arr="$array"
    for elem in "${arr[@]}"; do
        if [[ $elem =~ (^|[^[:alpha:]])$value([^[:alpha:]]|$) ]]; then
           printf '%s\n' "$elem"
        fi
    done
done
```

Optionally, you can also print the array from which it is found at using the `array` variable

```
printf 'Array Name = %s\n' "$array"
```

Also see [BashFAQ/006 - How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006)